# Why does this closure work?

Tags: javascript, closures

Say I have a simple function that alerts a message:

```
function callMessage(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
```

Now when I call it like so, it does not work. Throws error "hey is not defined"

```
function sayHi(){
        var hey = "hi there"
        setTimeout("callMessage(hey)", 1000);
    }
    sayHi();
```

But when I call it inside an anonymous function it does work:

```
function sayHi(){
        var hey = "hi there"
        setTimeout(function(){callMessage(hey);}, 1000);
    }
    sayHi();
```

Why is the "hey" variable only visible when I put it inside an anonymous function?

Comment: i would also try this; `setTimeout("var hey = 'hi there'; callMessage(hey)", 1000);`

Comment: If I were you, I'd read something like - http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the first example, the code is evaluated *after* the timer expired and the current scope was left. `hey` is undefined at that moment.

The second example - the proper way to use `setTimeout` - uses an anonymous function created when invoking `setTimeout()`. This anonymous function also receives a copy of the current scope.

Comment: In the second example the closure's body isn't evaluated until then either.

Comment: It isn't *executed* until later. The first one is *literally* evaluated (`eval()`) with no hint on which scope is to be used because its "just a string".

Comment: That makes sense. I did not know anonymous functions has a copy of its parent scope

Answer (score 6):

"callMessage(hey)" is a string, not a closure. It's evaluated when the timeout runs, and at this point the variable hey isn't in scope.

Answer (score 3):

it's normal.

The second example creates what we call a fixture, this is an execution context. hey variable variable is saved to be used by the anonymous function in memory.

In your first example, the hey variable is not saved in a fixture (because javascript can't know that you will used the variable after) and so can not be retrieved when the string is evaluated